# MVC Client Side Validator - passes boolean as a string

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation, client-side-validation

I'm trying to pass a boolean parameter from the 'GetClientValidationRules' method of a validator.
However the parameter comes through as a string.
Is it possible to pass the parameter as an actual boolean value?

Code for reference:

Server-side:

```
public override IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules()
{
    var rule = new ModelClientValidationRule()
    {
        ErrorMessage = "This is an error."
        ValidationType = "test"
    }
    rule.ValidationParameters.Add("test", true);
    yield return rule;
}
```

Client-side:

```
$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add("test", ["test"], function(options) {
    var parameter = options.params.test;

    if (parameter) { // Always true, because parameter === "True" (string value)
        ...
    }
});
```

I understand that i could just use 'if (parameter === "True")' but would like to avoid doing so if possible.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How about using `var parameter = !!(options.params.test);`? It will convert `test` to boolean directly in JS side.

Comment: !!"False" also evaluates to true. So this conversion will not function correctly. Thanks for your efforts anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately all values are passed as strings, so you'll have to parse it there.

However, you can pass it to the validation method as a boolean:

```
$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add("test", ["test"], function (options) {
    var parameter = options.params.test;

    options.rules["myMethod"] = parameter.toLowerCase() === "true";
    // add other options, such as the validation message
});

$.validator.addMethod("myMethod", function (value, element, params) {
    // 'params' would be the boolean value 'true'
});
```

Comment: That's what I was afraid of :( Looks like i'll just bite the bullet, and parse it.
As a side note - Boolean(parameter) would not function correctly as Boolean("False") evaluates to true.

Comment: `Boolean(x)` is same as `!!(x)` in this case, hence indeed it requires additional function to parse string as boolean value instead relying on standard string-to-boolean conversion.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto Yep, exactly.
I've just added a parseBoolean function which does: return String(val).toLowerCase() == "true";

Comment: Will - if you'd like to edit your answer with a more correct parse, then i'll accept it :)

Comment: @Luke I went ahead and updated the parse line. If you'd like to have the null check included or something else, feel free to propose an edit to it.

Answer (score 1):

The default boolean parsing methods like `!!(parameter)` or `Boolean(parameter)` may not working properly here since it always returns `true` if `parameter` contains any kind of strings, hence you need an additional function returning `Boolean` to parse it properly:

```
function parseBoolean(value) {
    // return value.toString().toLowerCase() === "true" also work here
    return String(value).toLowerCase() === "true";
}
```

Then, Will Ray's code should be modified to use that function shown below:

```
$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add("test", ["test"], function (options) {
    var parameter = options.params.test;

    // parse as boolean value here
    options.rules["myMethod"] = parseBoolean(parameter);

    // add other options, such as the validation message
});

$.validator.addMethod("myMethod", function (value, element, params) {
    // 'params' would be the boolean value 'true'
});
```